# ActiveDirectory query performance for not including

Tags: performance, active-directory

I'm curious as to whether the following will negatively impact performance in a significant way...

I have a web form with an input box and grid (could be any form of application really) and allows the user to search Active Directory for users...I don't want user accounts that have the $ as part of there sAMAccountName and so am wondering whether I should have them returned and then filter them out in a loop in the application or whether they should be excluded in the ActiveDirectory filter like the following:

```
(&(objectCateogry=person)(objectClass=user)(!(sAMAccountName=*$*))(cn=<Insert User Query>))
```

I guess it's the `*$*` that i'm concerned will impact performance...any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would include `(!(sAMAccountName=*$*))` in the query for the following reasons:

1. It is indexed in Active Directory so searches are quick.
2. In most environments domain controllers aren't hit as hard as web servers and have CPU and RAM to spare.

I'm just guessing but I would think that the extra entries that the domain controllers will have to process and send to the web server would actually make everything take a little longer. You could try it both ways in your environment and measure the difference.

Also, you could take a look at the classes in `System.DirectoryServices.Protocols` if you're concerned with performance.

Answer (score 0):

The filter about AD as follwing:

```
class ExpressionTemplates
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The start with expression. eg: "({0}={1}*)".
    /// </summary>
    public readonly static string StartWithExpression = "({0}={1}*)";

    /// <summary>
    /// The end with expression. eg: "({0}=*{1})".
    /// </summary>
    public readonly static string EndWithExpression = "({0}=*{1})";

    /// <summary>
    /// The has a value expression. eg: "({0}=*)".
    /// </summary>
    public readonly static string HasAValueExpression = "({0}=*)";

    /// <summary>
    /// The has no value expression. eg: "(!{0}=*)".
    /// </summary>
    public readonly static string HasNoValueExpression = "(!{0}=*)";

    /// <summary>
    /// The is expression. eg: "({0}={1})".
    /// </summary>
    public readonly static string IsExpression = "({0}={1})";

    /// <summary>
    /// The is not expression. eg: "(!{0}={1})".
    /// </summary>
    public readonly static string IsNotExpression = "(!{0}={1})";

    /// <summary>
    /// The and expression. eg: "(&amp;{0})".
    /// </summary>
    public readonly static string And = "(&{0})";
    /// <summary>
    /// The or expression. eg: "(|{0})".
    /// </summary>
    public readonly static string Or = "(|{0})";

    /// <summary>
    /// The parenthesis expression. eg: "({0})".
    /// </summary>
    public readonly static string Parenthesis = "({0})";

    /// <summary>
    /// The join expression. eg: "{0}{1}".
    /// </summary>
    public readonly static string Join = "{0}{1}";
}
```

You can refer my OSS project which base on ActiveRecord pattern as following(Because it is open source you can find out how to operate the AD with DirectoryEntry, DirectoryEntry is not only support the LDAP protocol but also IIS, WIN and so on, so I develop this lib):

```
class ComplexFilterUnitTest : BaseUnitTest
{
    [TestCase]
    public void TestComplexFilter()
    {
        IFilter filter =
            new And(
                new IsUser(),
                new Is(OrganizationalUnitAttributeNames.OU, "pangxiaoliangOU"),
                new Or(
                        new StartWith(AttributeNames.CN, "pang"),
                        new And(
                            new EndWith(AttributeNames.CN, "liu"),
                            new Is(PersonAttributeNames.Mail, "mv@live.cn")
                            )
                    )
                );
        Assert.AreEqual("(&(objectClass=user)(ou=pangxiaoliangOU)(|(cn=pang*)(&(cn=*liu)(mail=mv@live.cn))))", filter.BuildFilter());
        foreach (var userObject in UserObject.FindAll(this.ADOperator, filter))
        {
            using (userObject)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(userObject.DisplayName);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

https://landpyactivedirectory.codeplex.com/documentation

And you will find it easy to operate the AD with it, if you have no interest with it please ignore my answer.
Any question about AD please contact me :)